# python performance issue while searching in a huge list

Tags: list, performance, search, python-3.7

I need to speed up (dramatically) the search in a "huge" single dimension list of unsigned values. The list has 389.114 elements, and I need to perform a check before I add an item to make sure it doesn't already exist
I do this check 15 millions times...
Of course, it takes too much time
The fastest way I found was :

```
if this_item in my_list:
    i = my_list.index(this_item)
else:
    my_list.append(this_item)
    i = len(my_list)
    ...
```

I am building a dataset from time series logs
One column of these (huge) logs is a text message, which is very redondant
To dramatically speed up the process, I transform this text into an unsigned with Adler32(), and get a unique numeric value, which is great
Then I store the messages in a PostgreSQL database, with this value as index

For each line of my log files (15 millions all together), I need to update my database of unique messages (389.114 unique messages)
It means that for each line, I need to check if the message ID belongs to my in memory list

I tried "... in list", same with dictionaries, numpy arrays, transforming the list in a string and using string.search(), sql query in the database with good index...
Nothing better than "if item in list" when the list is loaded into memory (very fast)

```
if this_item in my_list:
    i = my_list.index(this_item)
else:
    my_list.append(this_item)
    i = len(my_list)
```

For 15 millions iterations with some stuff and NO search in the list:
- It takes 8 minutes to generate 2 tables of 15 millions lines (features and targets)
- When I activate the code above to check if a message ID already exists, it takes 1 hour 35 mn ...

How could I optimize this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Testing membership of a set is fast.

Comment: Sorry to tell you but your question is not good. You are not just asking suggestions, but **performance** suggestions on a specific problem you are solving yet you only provided an extremely vague statement and showing 2 lines of pseudocode. Performance depends very strictly on **exactly** what you are doing. For example I could tell you to just drop the `my_list.index` call in that code since you don't need the index of the element in those 2 lines. *Evidently* you actually do need that information but depending on how and when you need it the fastest implementation could change dramatically.

Comment: For example: you could first add all those "messages" and only once you are done you can build a mapping from messages to indices and use that to perform fasts lookups over the index. No idea whether this is feasible or you need an "online" algorithm or whatever. In any case if you want performance suggestions you **must** provide a minimal **working** example that people can use to actually profile the possible solutions... or you want people throwing random choices at you, you then need to implement them and come back saying "this is worse than before"? Wasted time from both parts.

Comment: The example is as simple as I wrote. I run through a huge list of logs reading lines one by one from some files, and for each line I read (=1 string to parse with split), I call a function to transform/simplify it, and then write a new line in an output file.

Comment: That part of the code has no interest I think for the problem. The function I call extracts all "columns" of the log string, and one of them is a text message. This text message may happen several times in different logs. That means that for 15 millions lines of logs, I call 15 millions times the function, that will check 15 millions times if the txt message is not already stored and indexed

Comment: My question is about how to check if a message is already in a list? To simplify, I transformed the text message into an unsigned value with the Adler32() function. So each message is in fact an unsigned ID

Comment: I have 389.114 different unique values in a list. And anytime I want to add one, I must check if the value already exists in the list. this is time consuming just to check. If it doesn't exist then I need some more code to add it in the list, together with adding it in the database. But after the first pass, once almost all messages are in the list, the loop is just checking if the value is in the list, and it must return the index

Comment: So my question could be : what object could be the most effective to go through and check if an item already exists? And if it does, returns an index of its position

Comment: And in that specific example (messages transformed into unsigned IDs), I don't even need to call my_list.index(), because I already have the index. So the only question is about "item in list". Is it the fastest way to check if an item exists in a list ?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is, roughly, this:

```
my_list = []
for this_item in collection:
  if this_item in my_list:
    i = my_list.index(this_item)
  else:
    my_list.append(this_item)
    i = len(my_list)
    ...
```

Then it will run in O(n^2) time since the `in` operator for lists is O(n).

You can achieve linear time if you use a dictionary (which is implemented with a hash table) instead:

```
my_list = []
table = {}
for this_item in collection:
  i = table.get(this_item)
  if i is None:
    i = len(my_list)
    my_list.append(this_item)
    table[this_item] = i
  ...
```

Of course, if you don't care about processing the items in the original order, you can just do:

```
for i, this_item in enumerate(set(collection)):
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you Alex (and Mark initially).

Comment: Thank you Alex (and Mark initially). You're right, using a set() instead of a list() improves the membership test (from 2x faster to 20x faster with huge lists)!! For my test I do not need to retrieve an index, because the index is the value which is stored, so no need to get it. Just need to test the membership of an unsigned to a set of unsigned (instead of a list).

Comment: To make it very simple, I still use a list to get the initial sql query result, and to add an element if it is new. But I copy the list into a set with my_set=set(my_list), anytime I modify my_list (adding an element), and then: my_item in my_set is much faster than my_item in my_list! Thanks a lot

Comment: I read 10 log files for a total of 15 millions lines, line by line. For each line I process the "columns" (split), to transform text into numbers, storing the dictionary into a PostgreSQL database (for later queries). That part was time consuming just to check if a message was already stored. Once a line is "simplified" with joints instead of text, I store it in a final file to merge all logs, which are TimeSeries, and then I load this file into a list in Memory (1Gb), sort the list by TimeStamp, and rewrite the file.

Comment: Then I read this ultimate sorted file and store the data into 2 tables in PostgreSQL for later Machine Learning. I can also optimize the last part, trying to do it in 1 step, but actually the whole process takes 5 minutes (instead of 1h30, thanks to the set() ;-)), and it is already much much better

Comment: Note that sets also have an `add` function, so you can create a set with `my_set = set()` and then later do `my_set.add(my_item)`. This will be MUCH faster than recreating the set from another list several times and might even get you under 1 minute.

Comment: Erratum:... The whole process [before inserting 2x 15 millions lines in the PostgreSQL database] took 5mn instead of 1h30. I am actually testing Numba to see if a JIT compilation of recurrent functions gives a gain, and the next step will be to use a big data database to store the tables for ML, like Apache Spark or Hadoop Hive... but this is another story :-)

Comment: Thanks Alex, you're right, I didn't face the problem because actually the messages have been created, so I just need to check in the set(). But in the process, it should be much faster (and clever :-) to use set methods instead of copying again...

Comment: If the information may be useful, I tried Numba to compile just in time, but finally most of the functions I use are not actually managed by Numba (file descriptor, adler32, private classes and functions returning a value, global variables...). So I got just 1 function very simple that could be compiled, and it doesn't bring value, even if it is called millions of times.

Comment: The next step now is about storing the datasets in a timeseries database (ie: influx) to perform ML. Because of course PostgreSQL is good for dictionaries, but definitely not adapted for big data